# How to add element with the same key in dictionary?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import json

dictionary = {}
variable = 0

for i in range(5):
    variable += 1
    dictionary['number'] = variable

print(json.dumps(dictionary))
```

```
Output: {"number": 5}
```

I think my code just changing value in dictionary instead of creating new one.
I want the dictionary look like this:

```
{"number": 1, "number": 2, "number": 3, "number": 4, "number": 5}
```

i know that i can do this:

```
{"number": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

but i want to do like i said before. I just want json with the same keys and different variables so if there is another option to achieve my goal, then tell me.

Comment: You can't have multiple keys all called `number`.  Dictionary keys are unique.  (What would you want `dictionary['number']` to return?)

Comment: You're missing the entire point of dictionary keys.  If you could actually create a dict with duplicate keys like that - what would you expect `dictionary['number']` to return?  How would you ever retrieve the other four values?

Comment: Please clarify why you do not want `{"number": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}`. It's simply the most logical solution, able to still take advantage of a dict's efficiency in membership lookup. Any other solution would make the use of a dict pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple of the same key but you can have a list of multiple values for the one key:

```
import json

dictionary = {}
variable = 0
dictionary['number'] = []


for i in range(5):
    variable += 1
    dictionary['number'].append(variable)

print(json.dumps(dictionary))
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible with Python dictionaries. Python will always overwrite a key if you try to use it more than once.

You could try a list of single key-value dicts to get close:

`[{"number": 1}, {"number": 2}, {"number": 3}, {"number": 4}, {"number": 5}]`